# Secret info & EC2 CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, credentials

With secret code such as MongoDB password, Firebase admin password in my NodeJS server code, I am wondering how I should go about deploying this to EC2 (and multiple EC2 instances with CodeDeploy / AutoScaling, in the future).

Is there a common way to go about this - keeping your credentials secure? You could argue that the security layer is at the instance: make sure that there is no unwanted access to your instance(s) and you should be good. But is this really the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Given a service that has a secret password in its config file called `config.json`, create a software config file called `config-development.json`:

`password=[PASSWORD]`

During Codedeploy, there are scripts or hooks, that run during the deployment cycle eg BeforeInstall, Install, AfterInstall. During the AfterInstall script execution, get the secret from the parameter store via cli, store it in a variable, and then replace the `[PASSWORD]` value in the json file, using sed or any search and replace command line tool.

Rename the resulting file to the `config.json`, and restart the service.

This approach will allow you to keep secrets out of your repo, and use only value from the  parameter store.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks-list

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is a way to specify parameters (such as passwords) upon pushing a CodeDeploy revision? And you can tell the command line to store them in a certain file, and then have a Linux 'sed' script to replace the value for the relevant files? I wasn't able to read more about the parameter store from the link in question, though

Comment: Yes. For cli command example see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html